# Finding mergable groups in a directed graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I have a directed graph, $G = (V,E)$ (a dependency graph actually) and I want to find groups of nodes that can be considered as a single unit.

I define a group as a set of nodes, $A$, such that any node outside of the group, $v \in A^c$, that has an edge to a node inside, must have an edge to every other member of the group:

if $\exists u \in A: (u,v) \in E$ then $|\{\ (v,w)\ |\ \forall w \in A\ \wedge\ (v,w) \in E\ \}| = |A|$

Once groups are found, then a merge can be made, i.e. add a node $u'$ in G and for all edges from $v \in A^c$ to $u \in A,$ make an edge from $v$ to $u'$. Finally, remove all original nodes and corresponding edges in G, thus constructing a reduced graph.

This is similar to reducing a state machine.

Comment: The set $V$ satisfies this condition.

Comment: Sounds like you want a modular decomposition.

Comment: Given Yuval Filmus's comment, I suspect there is some additional requirement you haven't told us.  Can you specify the problem more precisely?  The input is a directed graph $G$.  What is the desired output?  Is the desired output a group, any group?  Is it a list of all possible groups?  Is it a partition of the nodes into groups?  Something else?  Please edit the question to clarify the problem statement, then this can be considered for re-opening at that time.  Thank you!

Comment: @D.W. Added a clarification on what i want to achieve. But the gist is basically a reduced graph

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the feedback.  As Yuval says, the set $A=V$ satisfies the condition.  And your edits don't answer my questions  about what you want if there are multiple possible ways to choose a set $A$ (any arbitrary solution?  all of them? the smallest?  something else?).  Incidentally, I notice that the mathematical condition doesn't seem to match the English statement, because the direction of the edge is swapped.  Instead of $(u,v)\in E$ did you mean $(v,u) \in E$?

Comment: I also don't see a question in this post. What _is_ the question?

Comment: Hmm, maybe im just usure of exactly what I want. I'll think it over and do some edit's (or remove it) when I'm more sure of where exactly I want to go